# Find the vector whose tip is some "orthogonal" distance from another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

I created couple of quick diagrams of this seemingly simple trigonometry problem I'm trying to solve in code right now:

Example A:

[image: Two vectors separated by an "orthogonal" distance of r]

Example B (here we just change $m$ and $n$):
[image]

I'm trying to determine $w$ given the values of $m, n, a, b, r$. I can guarantee $-1 <= m, n, a, b <= 1$ and $r > 0$.

Naively solving with angles for Example A we get:

$$w = \frac{r}{sin(θ)}$$

where $θ$ is the angle between the two vectors:

$$ θ = 90° - arctan(\frac{m}{n}) - arctan(\frac{b}{a}) $$

However, in the diagram provided above, it's valid for either $n$ or $a$ to be $0$ which breaks arctan (or atan2). Note: $n$ and $a$ cannot both be zero simultaneously because the angle between the two vectors cannot be $>=90°$.

This approach does not work for Example B. I'm not sure of a single approach that solves both.

It feels like there should be a clean way to do this? I would appreciate any and all insight.

Edit 1: added note based on comment

Edit 2: added another example diagram and hopefully clarified the question.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that everything takes place in the positive quadrant, from the diagram and your working. If you assume $n = 0$ or $a = 0$, then this means that the the whole image will be squished onto one of the axes, which will surely break the problem, not just the working out.

Comment: Hey Theo thanks for looking at the question. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the _whole_ image won't get squished. If we take the diagram and leave everything the same ($a,b,m,r$) but we change $n$ to equal zero, then the $m$, $n$ triangle will be squished (so $w$ will be horizontal) but the $a,b$ triangle will be unchanged.

Indeed if _both_ $n$ _and_ $a$ are zero, then there is no solution. Generally, whenever the angle between the two vectors is $>=90°$ there is no solution.

Comment: I think the question is somewhat unclear, because I think you are trying to consider cases beyond what your diagram and working out suggest. The way you have drawn the diagram, the rays all lie in the positive quadrant and the three angles sum to $90^\circ$, which you used in your working out. If you keep these implicit assumptions, then the triangle on the upper-left (the $m$-$n$ triangle) will squish into the $x$-axis when $n = 0$, squishing the other two triangles into this axis. If you don't want to assume this, then you can't necessarily assume this angle sum.

Comment: I agree that this naive "angle sum" approach does not work. This is kind of why I'm asking the question in the first place. I should clarify that all of the variables are independent e.g., setting $n = 0$ does not affect $a$ or $b$ so squishing the $m,n$ triangle does not affect the $a,b$ triangle. I've updated the question. Please let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{u}=(a,b)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(m,n)$, then $$\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\cos\theta$$ $$\implies \theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|}\right)=\arccos\left(\frac{am+bn}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(m^2+n^2)}}\right).$$ **Note**: this assumes the $m,n$ and $a,b$ triangles are really just two points in the plane, i.e. one of the sides always lies on an axis.